# Check if floppydisk is available or not from an assembly language bootloader

Tags: assembly, x86-16, bootloader, emu8086, floppy

I have a question about how to check if a floppy drive is available or not, using assembly language.  I checked if the RAM memory is enough, but I have no idea how to check if a floppy drive is available. I tried this: `CMP AH,0` `JNE disk_error`, but when I put this after the check for RAM, nothing happens. When I put in *continueToLoad*: `CMP AX,0` `JNE fatal_disk_error`, it works fine, but an error message appears after loading bar. [Loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ef6kM.jpg) ***I need that error message to appear before the loading bar.***  [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szBKv.jpg)

```
main:
    MOV DS,AX 
    PUSH CS
    POP DS
    MOV AH,0x00 
    MOV AL,0x03
    INT 0x10    
    CALL ClearScreen

    MOV BL,1010b        
    MOV BP,StrLoadKernel    
    MOV CX,length   
    MOV DH,13       
    MOV DL,30           
    CALL PrintString

    MOV BL,1010b        
    MOV BP,StrReboot    
    MOV CX,length2      
    MOV DH,14       
    MOV DL,30           
    CALL PrintString

readKeys:
    CALL PressKey
    CMP AL,00011011b ; ESC binary code
    JE Reboot
    CMP AL,00001101b ; ENTER binary code
        
    CALL ClearScreen
        
    MOV BL,1010b        
    MOV BP,StrLoading   
    MOV CX,length4      
    MOV DH,14       
    MOV DL,35           
    CALL PrintString    
      
    JE LoadKernel
    loop readKeys

    jmp $

LoadKernel:
    ;CHECK IF RAM MEMORY > 64MB
    MOV AH,0x88
    INT 0x15            
    CLC  
    CMP AX,0xFA00  
    MOV BL,0011b                         
    JNC printLoader
     CALL ClearScreen 
        MOV BL,1100b        
        MOV BP,StrErrorRAM  
        MOV CX,length3      
        MOV DH,13       
        MOV DL,25               
        CALL PrintString  
        
        MOV BL,1100b        
        MOV BP,press_key    
        MOV CX,length6      
        MOV DH,14       
        MOV DL,25                  
        CALL PrintString
        
        CALL PressKey
        CALL Reboot     
      JMP readKeys 
    JMP printLoader 

changeToBlue: 
MOV BL,1001b    

JMP printLoader

changeToGreen:
MOV BL,1010b    
    
JMP printLoader

changeToRed:
MOV BL,0100b    
    
JMP printLoader

continueToLoad: 
        MOV AX,0
        MOV DL,0
        INT 0x13         
        
    ;load kernel
        MOV AX,kernel 
        MOV ES,AX
        MOV BX,0        
        
        MOV AH,02h 
        MOV AL,01h 
        MOV CH,0h  
        MOV CL,02  
        MOV DH,0   
        MOV DL,0   
        INT 0x13   
           
        CMP AH, 0                     
        jne fatal_disk_error

jmp kernel:0

RET

CALL printLoader

printLoader:   
        MOV BP,symbol       ; stringul care dorim sa il afisam
        MOV CX,symbolLength ; marimea stringului
        MOV DH,16       ; randul (x)
        MOV DL,[count]      ; coloana (y)
        
        CALL PrintString
        
        INC DL
        INC DL
        INC DL
        MOV [count],DL
        
        CALL wait2sec
        
        MOV AL,[pas]
        INC AL
        MOV [pas],AL

        CMP AL,3
        JE changeToBlue
    
        CMP AL,6
        JE changeToGreen

        CMP AL,9
        JE changeToRed 
                
        CMP AL,10
        JE continueToLoad

    loop printLoader

ClearScreen:
    MOV AX,0600h 
    MOV CX,0000h
    MOV BH,0Ah
    MOV DX,1850h
    int 0x10    
RET

PressKey:
    ;read a key
    MOV AH,0
    INT 0x16
RET

PrintString:
    MOV AH, 0x13
    MOV AL,0
    MOV BH,0    
    INT 0x10
    ; hide cursor
    mov AH,0x01
    MOV CX,2607h
    INT 0x10
RET

Reboot:
    db 0x0ea
    dw 0x0000
    dw 0xffff
RET

wait2sec:
    MOV AH,0x86
    MOV CX,0008h
    MOV DX,6480h
    int 0x15
RET

fatal_disk_error:
    CALL ClearScreen 
    MOV AX,0  
    MOV ES,AX 
    
    MOV BL,1100b        
    MOV BP,disk_error   
    MOV CX,length5      
    MOV DH,16       
    MOV DL,30
    call PrintString
    CALL wait2sec
    CALL PressKey
    CMP AL,00011011b ; ESC binary code
    jmp Reboot
RET

StrLoadKernel: db "Press ENTER to load the KERNEL "
length equ $-StrLoadKernel

StrReboot: db "Press ESC to restart "
length2 equ $-StrReboot
                                                        
StrErrorRAM: db "Loading cancelled! ERROR : RAM < 64mb."
length3 equ $-StrErrorRAM    

StrLoading: db "Loading... "
length4 equ $-StrLoading  

disk_error: db "Floppy error! Press any key... "
length5 equ $-disk_error   

press_key: db "Press any key to restart!" 
length6 equ $-press_key

kernel equ 1000h

symbol: db 219 
symbolLength equ $-symbol

count db 25

pas  db 0

 510-($-$$) db 0

DW 0xAA55
```

Comment: http://wiki.osdev.org/CMOS#Register_0x10

Comment: I think you can check the port for availability of drive, IIRC.

Comment: How can i check with IIRC? Some links?

Comment: Hi, cad. I tried cmp AH,0 JNE fatal_disk_error, but i need that message error appears before the loading bar.

Comment: Why do you need to check for to see if a floppy disk exists? If this boot sector code is located on the floppy disk then the disk obviously exists otherwise the code would have never been loaded from the disk and executed. If the boot sector isn't on the floppy disk why are you trying to access the floppy disk?

Comment: Ross Ridge, i don't know where write this CMP AH,0 JNE  fatal_disk_error for that message error appears before the loading bar.

Comment: You can't do that by moving just one line. You can't program in assembly language by only cutting & pasting code. You're going to have to learn how actually to program in assembly language. Unfortunately that's something we can't help you with.

Answer (score 3):

To find out if you got a floppy drive use the **GetEquipmentStatus** BIOS function.

```
int 11h
```

It returns a value in the AX register. Bits 6 and 7 together tell you how many floppy disk drives are attached to the system.

```
00 = 1 drive
01 = 2 drives
10 = 3 drives
11 = 4 drives
```

Only use bits 6 and 7 *if bit 0 is ON*

Another method would be to see if you can successfully get the status of the floppy drive through BIOS function 01h of `int 13h`.

```
mov dl, 0
mov ah, 01h
int 13h
cmp ah, 0
jne disk_error
```

Do consult the full list of *DiskControllerStatusBits* because a mere `cmp ah, 0` could prove to be a little simplistic.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to know if a floppy drive is present.

You only need to know if device 0 (or maybe, the device the BIOS told you that you booted from) behaves like a floppy drive would; and if the device happens to be (e.g.) USB flash or a CD/DVD emulating a floppy drive then that's fine. For this purpose use [int 0x13, ah = 0x08, Get Drive Parameters](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0621.htm) and examine the results.

If you actually do need to know if a floppy drive is present; then it's a whole world of pain. The BIOS can be misconfigured (and its CMOS wrong), there may be a USB floppy drive that the BIOS doesn't know about and/or doesn't even support, etc.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the **GetEquipmentStatus** BIOS function mentionned by @user3144770 there's another BIOS function **GetDiskType** you can use.

```
mov dl, 0
mov ah, 15h
int 13h
```

If the carry flag is set there was an error. (Status in AH)
If the carry flag is clear you get a value in AH that informs you about the drive specified in the DL argument.

```
AH=0 no drive
AH=1 floppy without change-line support
AH=2 floppy with change-line support
AH=3 hard disk
```